# Lambda terms forming non-abelian groups

Tags: lambda-calculus

I was wondering what kind of groups could be constructed with Lambda terms, where the group operation is application? For example, $a* b =c$ would mean $ab\to_{\beta}^{*} c$. Is this even possible?

EDIT: I don't think groups are possible, but I did find a group of sets which are closed under application:

Let $I_0=\lambda x.x$ and $I_{n+1}=\lambda y.I_n$, where $y\not\in\text{bv}\left(I_n\right)$.
Then $S_n=\bigcup_{i=0}^{n}\left\{I_i\right\}$ is closed under application for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: And what is the group inverse operation?

Comment: @Pseudonym I'm not sure if it would be possible then, since the application of inverses should be commutative. What about sets of terms $S$ such that $\forall (a,b)\in S$ the reductions of $ab$ and $ba$ are also in $S$?

Comment: Just realised you only need the reductions of $ab$ to be in $S$. An example though might be $\left \{\lambda x.x,\lambda y.\lambda x.x\right\}$.

Comment: pick out the lambda terms that denote naturals. Mathematical operations on naturals such as multiplication, addition, division etc. is defined on them. That may give you a starting point to define a group. The non-abelian part may need some more thinking.

Comment: $ab\to_\beta^\ast c$ is not a well-defined group operation, since for example both $(\lambda xy. y)pq\to_\beta^\ast( \lambda y.y)q$ and $(\lambda xy. y)pq\to_\beta^\ast q)$.  Or maybe you want to require that $c$ must be a normal form? But then it's still not well-defined because not every application reduces to a normal form.

Comment: I would require $c$ to be in normal form - and yeah, it's true not every application has a normal form but that would be required for the application of all pairs of elements in the group (since it is possible - e.g. in the example of sets closed under application I gave)

Comment: So I think we're looking for a family of $F$ lambda-terms such that for every $a, b$ in $F$, the application $ab$ has a normal form $c$, the normal form $c$ is also in $F$, and there is an identity element and inverses also in $F$.  Is that right?

Comment: (Incidentally I think it might be easier to deal with this with combinators rather than lambda-terms.  They are interconvertible, but the combinators are more concise, and avoid issues such as $\alpha$-equivalence.)

Comment: @MarkDominus That is correct - and yeah that might be helpful

Comment: I think it ought to be possible to realize any group as a family of lambda terms. If I figure out the details I will post.

Comment: @MarkDominus The problem I had was finding inverses for elements which are also in the group